# Docker swarm container cannot resolve address of container in another node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have init a swarm on my Vm and joined another Vm to my swarm as a manager. Then I overlay a network  `docker network create --attachable --driver overlay my-net`.

I then ran docker stack deploy to deploy my services. However when i exec into one container and try to nslookup a container from another node. eg `nslookup <container_name>`

I got :

```
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

** server can't find <container_name>: NXDOMAIN
```

nslookup to containers in the same node works though.

Im guessing that my DNS is not working when it comes to resolving address from another node and Im wondering why.

Additional info:

netstat -l for both nodes:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:2377               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:7946               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:30283              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:30284              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:30285              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:30289              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:30290              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:30291              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*
udp        0      0 *:4789                  *:*
udp6     768      0 [::]:7946               [::]:*
```

ufw status shows inactive.

docker inspect   (partial result)
could it be that my peer ip 10.0.0.5 is incorrect?

```
"Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "c7feabf505ba",
                "IP": "10.0.0.5"
            },
            {
                "Name": "073e551404e8",
                "IP": "137.116.149.79"
            }
        ]
```

docker info node 1:

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 15
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: ro2p9n7o33darkuylentq1nx0
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 01q4hei9hzibq3x8m36pzqo8c
 Managers: 2
 Nodes: 2
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 168.63.239.163
 Manager Addresses:
  137.116.149.79:2377
  168.63.239.163:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-1025-azure
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.853GiB
Name: blockcord-staging2
ID: UT5F:4ZFW:4PRT:LGFS:JIV4:3YAD:DK5I:BIYL:FU6P:ZFEB:3OD3:U5EX
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

docker info node 2:

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 15
Server Version: 18.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: osmwr2fcrcg8mazopkanf4gr7
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 01q4hei9hzibq3x8m36pzqo8c
 Managers: 2
 Nodes: 2
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 10.0.1.6
 Manager Addresses:
  137.116.149.79:2377
  168.63.239.163:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: d64c661f1d51c48782c9cec8fda7604785f93587
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-1025-azure
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.885GiB
Name: doc2us-staging
ID: JG7Q:HZBH:7WIF:22GC:PZQQ:EXJC:ZDPT:C2SA:TDRM:XJ4M:KKX4:OAEI
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Can you please provide docker info state of both node ? I suspect that it attach to same network

Comment: hi @dotnetstep. I have updated with new infos

Comment: I don't have exact answer as of now as I have to run experiment but following thing is similar : https://forums.docker.com/t/service-in-swarm-running-on-different-nodes-are-not-reachable-through-overlay-network/28118

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason was because when I use the docker swarm join command, docker automatically join using my internal ip.

I have to do it as just

docker swarm join --token ......  --advertise-addr .

credits to https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1429#issuecomment-329325410

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day!

Comment: same here, the problem was the node behind NAT and solved by appending `--advertise-addr <public ip>`